# Double Buffering with awt

Tags: java, swing, awt, doublebuffered

Is double buffering (in java) possible with awt? Currently, I'm aware that swing should not be used with awt, so I can't use BufferStrategy and whatnot (I already have some code written in awt that I don't want to rewrite in swing).

If double buffering is possible with awt, do I have to write the buffer by hand? Unlike swing, awt doesn't seem to have the same built-in double buffering capability.

If I do have to write the code by hand, is there a good tutorial to look at? Or is it just easier/advisable for a novice programmer to use swing instead?

Sorry about the multi-step question. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easily answered on the web.  Just search for "double buffer awt" and you'll find LOTS of examples.  You can even see [an old example](http://www.astro.wisc.edu/~dolan/java/publicsource/Constellations.java) I wrote myself in 1998 in Java 1.0 AWT.  You just need to instantiate your own Graphics object and draw to an Image, then blit that image into a canvas.  Here's the key bit of code in my example:

```
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    if (doubleBuffer) {
      paintSky(top.gBuf);
      g.drawImage(top.buf, 0, 0, this);
    } else {
      paintSky(g);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I would say it's advisable to reuse the swing implementation if possible.

Comment: Oh dear, I can't run the code, because the newStuff() method isn't there. D:

Comment: @DDP: huh, well that's strange.  Obviously I haven't tried to compile that code in a decade...  The compiled code is running as an applet here: http://www.astro.wisc.edu/~dolan/java/Constellations.html so the source I linked must not be the right version.

Comment: All right, I'll just look into your source code anyway (Everything else seems to be in order). Many thanks for the pointers, Chris Dolan :D